# Start tomcat with jvm

Tags: linux, tomcat, ubuntu

Good day
In my current situation when the jvm crashes or needs to be restarted then the apache tomcat server has to be manually started. I was wondering if there is a way to force the tomcat to start when the jvm finishes starting up. I'm on an ubuntu linux machine.

Comment: I think you need to add more information to your question. "... the jvm crashes or needs to be restarted then the apache tomcat server has to be manually started". The Tomcat server actually is a Java program running on top of a JVM.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably a little bit confused - or there is a critical piece of information missing from your question: Tomcat is *not* something separate from the [JVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) - it is written in Java and its code is executed *within* the JVM. On Linux, you will typically have one JVM process for each Java application, such as a Tomcat instance.

Therefore you cannot "start Tomcat once the JVM finishes starting up" - whichever JVM your Tomcat setup is using will just start executing the server [bytecode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode) as soon as it is loaded. The Tomcat start-up scripts will launch it with the correct parameters as soon as they are invoked.

I believe that there are four parts to your *actual* problem:

- Determine what the exact behavior of your server is. Is the JVM actually crashing? Or is the Tomcat server encountering a critical exception? Or, perhaps, you just find your server in an unresponsive state? The Linux system logs and the Tomcat log files should contain enough information to tell what is happening.

  Or is your Tomcat server just not starting once the OS boots, and you just need to fix your Linux boot configuration?
- Determine *why* that behavior is happening. Is the JVM running out of memory and being terminated by the kernel? Is it crashing due to another issue? Is your web application stuck waiting on e.g. a dead DB server?
- Determine how to fix the actual problem. Restarting the application server on a regular basis is a good indication that you need to fix your Tomcat setup - or your application code.
- When you have done all you can with the previous steps, only then should you consider an automated solution to help restart your server. There are several service monitoring tools, such as [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) that you could use, although they usually need someone at least moderately experienced on Linux to set-up right.

Comment: I'm not confused, I know tomcat runs in the jvm, if the jvm crashes tomcat will cease to function because of that. But I would like to know if there is an easy way to configure tomcat or a shell script or how can I configure tomcat to start after the jvm startup.

Comment: @Kreender: that's what I am trying to tell you: The JVM does *not* start separately. The JVM is what loads and executes the Tomcat server code - you cannot separate the two. What is your *actual* problem?

Comment: I'm not talking about separating them. My actual problem is that sometimes the jvm crashes or is restarted and tomcat doesn't automatically start again and I would like to force the tomcat to start after the jvm finishes booting up in order to avoid a manual startup and save some time.

Comment: @Kreender You are definitely confused, and not listening to people who want to help you.

Comment: How am I confused?. That the jvm crashes an restarts is not a guarantee that the tomcat server is going to start again, you have to do it manually, I want to avoid that. Why is it the jvm crashing? I don't know, that analysis is another problem altogether, I want to do something to avoid the manual start. A solution would be a cron job that checks every X minutes if the tomcat process is up, if it isn't it could start the tomcat, but I don't like that solution because it seems costly. I'm not trying to be difficult, and I'm indeed reading all your input, sorry if I'm not being clear enough.

Comment: @Kreender: you are referring to the JVM as if it is a separate service. *It is not* . The JVM is basically an interpreter like Perl and Python. You are essentially asking the equivalent of how to get your program to start *after* the interpreter is loaded when doing `python MyProgram.py` or `perl MyProgram.pl`...

Comment: The JVM is both an interpreter and JIT compiler. I know that the tomcat server cannot start without the jvm running, it is obvious. But tomcat does not restart automatically after the jvm restarts after a crash and I would like to do that somehow. I have no idea why my point is not getting across, sorry for not being clear enough.

Comment: @Kreender: because you are saying that the JVM is starting, while the program in it (Tomcat) is not, which makes absolutely no sense... Tomcat runs *in* the JVM. Not *a* JVM - *its own* JVM. How is that JVM restarted anyway?

Comment: I suspect that what you are seeing is far different than what you are describing. Can you describe the *symptoms* of your problem, rather than whatever you *think* the cause is?
*"The server is not starting"* has a very different meaning than *"The server is not responding when I am trying to connect"*.